# RichTextBox only inserts first file on Drag&Drop

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, richtextbox

When dropping files into a RichTextBox using Drag&Drop only 1 file is inserted even if more files were dragged. How can I change the behaviour?

---

example form, that illustrates the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        RichTextBox rtb;

        public Form1()
        {
            rtb = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rtb.AllowDrop = true;
            Controls.Add(rtb);

            rtb.DragEnter += Rtb_DragEnter;
            rtb.DragDrop += Rtb_DragDrop;
        }

        private void Rtb_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }

        private void Rtb_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            StringCollection sFiles = new StringCollection();
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileDrop"))
            {
                sFiles.AddRange((string[])e.Data.GetData("FileDrop"));  //returns a list of files
                Clipboard.Clear();
                Clipboard.SetFileDropList(sFiles);
                rtb.Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.FileDrop));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the default copy behaviour. The same problem occurs when using [Ctrl]+[v].

You can work around that by pasting one file after another:

```
private void Rtb_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    StringCollection sFiles = new StringCollection();
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileDrop"))
    {
        foreach (string file in (string[])e.Data.GetData("FileDrop"))
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            sFiles.Clear();
            sFiles.Add(file);
            Clipboard.SetFileDropList(sFiles);
            rtb.Paste();  //it's not necessary to specify the format
        }
    }
}
```